# Query for sum of column values not giving me a value

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a GridView in my ASP Page where the user can change one of the values and the other is a read only value. I want that when the row is updated a query will execute that sums the value of one column to the other and changes it. Ex... Value1 + Value 2 = Value2. I wrote this in the code-behind:

```
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdated
    Dim connectionString As String = "mystring"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Select (Purchased + Actual) as Actual from Product", cn)


        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
    End Using
```

yet the value doesn't sum. A part of me says I need an update command to save the value or something like that but what I read in W3 and other places doesn't point me to that. I guess since there's different products (of course) I need a WHERE ProductID = @Parameter... right? Still that code should change the rest of the values and it doesn't. Any pointers or anything that flew over me? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You don't need to manually close your connection inside a `using` block (the dispose method is called automatically). Also, you may use `using` with the SqlCommand object as it implements the `IDisposable` interface as well.

Comment: code optimization ftw. Thanks.

Comment: Your SQL code does not update the table.  It just creates a result set with these calculations that you even do not capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want

```
Update Product Set Value2 = Value1 + Value2 
Where ProductId = @Parameter
```

Comment: yeah this should be it. i am facing a problem reading the label in the gridview. I made it a template field and I am using a Findcontrol command to get the value from it but VB throws this exceptionL: No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label to a known managed provider native type. .